# Do quotes in library include path in C++ mean base directory of the project?

Tags: c++, include

Do quotes in library include path in C++ mean base directory?

```
#include "header.h"
```

I would think it would be in the project folder, but I am wrong.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename

Comment: It is **very** related to the linked question. :-) The language standard doesn't contain anything about paths (some systems don't have any!), so it cannot define how files are searched for. It is all implementation defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#include <foo.h>` means that it will look for the file anywhere in the include path.

`#include "foo.h"` means to look relative to the directory of the file that the `#include` statement is written in, and fallback on the include path if it cannot be found locally.

Answer (score 1):

That will only look in the directory of the file. ie if you had the following setup:

```
folder: src
contents: header.c

folder: src/include
contents: header.h
```

If you had the line above in header.c, the preprocessor would not find the header.h file.